# Least Squares with two inequality constraints

Tags: r, minimize, least-squares

I have a least square problem with two different inequality problems. i can not use NNLS because its just solve least square problem with equality and inequality problems or just one inequality constraint. 
can i use NNLS  or any other algorithm or R package  that i can solve this least square problem?

```
    min|| Ax-b||^2    x = c(c, d, f) is a vector
    x >= 0 
    c + d * x + f * x >= 0
```

Comment: You can use the `quadprog` package (for general quadratic optimization problems) or `mgcv::pcls` (for constrained regression).

Comment: Actually i have looked at limSolve package but i think i can not use it because my first contraint is x_{i}>= 0 and i can not write this condition as G matrix in lsei.is there any other way?

Comment: Yes, you can still use `limSolve::lsei`. The `x >= 0` constraint can be modeled as `Gx >= H` where `G` is the identity matrix and `H` is a vector of zeroes.

Comment: If you are still interested in an answer, you'll need to clarify some of the confusion in your problem formulation above. If `x` is your unknown variable, the statement that `x = c(c, d, f)` is a vector and the `c + d * x + f * x >= 0` don't make much sense to me. Maybe provide sample data as an example?

Comment: Could you clarify the constraints? Thank You.